# Deer population.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Now suppose hunting is started in this preserve such that 10 deer are removed per week. The new differential equation becomes:

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = .02p(6-p)-.1$$

Determine the fate of the deer population if the initial population is 510 deer.

$$0 = .02p(6-p)-.1$$ Dividing by $.02$ gives:

$$0 = p(6-p)-5$$

$$-p^2+6p-5=0$$

$$p^2-6p+5=0$$

We get equilibrium points at $p = 1 , p = 5$

$$p'(6)= .02(6)(6-6)-.1= -.1$$

$$p'(2) = .02(2)(6-2)-.1 = .06$$

$$p'(0) = -.1$$

Putting this into a phase diagram tells me that $p = 5$ is stable and $p = 1$ is not stable. Since .1 = 10 deer, every unit on the phase diagram represents $100$ deer. Since $510$ is above $p = 5$ and the slope is negative above $p=5$ the population will decrease and stabilize at or around $500$

Comment: Is $p$ the same as $P$?  If so, please be consistent with your notation.

Comment: Yes it is the same thing i will correct that

Comment: @K.Gibson, take it easy. This forum is in the www . You can't have all people think the same. I did not down-vote this question.

Comment: Well its .02 and when I divide .1 by it I get 5

Comment: You are correct at this point. It is not clear why you evaluate the derivative at values 6 and 2?

Comment: so everything adds up? it stabilizes at 500

Comment: To study the behavior of the population I would assume that you need to find P(t). I am no authority on the subject but this is my guess.

Comment: What's your question?